# Selecting fonts for unicode block range in variable-pitch face

Tags: emacs

How can I select alternative fonts for the variable-pitch or fixed-pitch faces in Unicode?

```
  (set-face-attribute 'fixed-pitch nil :family "sans serif")
  (set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil :family "serif")
```

*I would like to be able to specify something like:*

```
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'arabic "Amiri" nil 'prepend)
```

Which separately would be for each face type.